# Query about Bruhat-Tits buildings over completions of fields with respect to a valuation, but the residue class field is not necessarily finite

Tags: algebraic-groups, buildings

I'm reading Soulé's article "Chevalley groups over polynomial rings", and he has a situation where $k$ is an arbitrary field, not necessarily finite, then you take a simple transcendental extension of $k$, $k(t)$, and complete it with respect to the valuation that sends $u/v$ to deg $v$-deg $u$, so that way you'll end up with a complete field which is not necessarily locally compact, then he starts talking about the affine Bruhat-Tits building of a Chevalley group scheme over that field.

So, I'm sort of wondering, is there a problem here from the field not necessarily being locally compact? Does Bruhat-Tits theory work totally fine for any field that's complete with respect to a valuation? Hoping someone can help me understand better here.

Comment: If you look at the original articles of Bruhat and Tits, they do not assume the residue field to be finite. Hence the frequent appearance in the theory of "bounded" (as opposed to compact) subgroups.